# What does service_name@configuration_file.conf do when running systemctl commands?

Tags: systemctl

What does the following systemctl command do?

```
$ sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service
```

I am unfamiliar with this particular syntax. What does the `@server.service` part of this command do? It looks like it might be pointing at some kind of configuration file called `server.service`?

Reference:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: At first glance this reminds me of this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/convert-run-at-startup-script-from-upstart-to-systemd-for-ubuntu-16 .

Comment: This could be a red-herring. It might be that the name `server.service` is both a file on the system and some kind of name passed to systemctl that just happens to have a period `.` in it

Comment: I guess it is true .